# Payment recurrent with stripe woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, payment-method

i am working on WordPress&woocommerce project in which i need to implement a method for recurrent payment with stripe, exactly 3 time in a year for the purchased product. 
Any suggestions? Maybe a plugin or programatlly.

By the way the price of the product is dynamic!

Comment: Checkout WooCommerce [subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/)

Comment: That's a good plug in i have checked i also have subsciptio-woocommerce-subscription but The total price of the product is dynamic, i mean the visitor can select multiple choices in the product page and depending in what he select the final price change just wanna know how to make the payment of that final price can be divided into 3 times!

Answer (score 0):

`mcon`'s suggestion in the comments is a good one.  Alternatively, you could build this with Stripe's [Subscriptions product](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions).